# MariaDB: Can I retrive duplicate column names without using 'AS'

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a lot of tables that use `id` as the primary key.  When I join several tables together and `select *`, only one of the id columns is displayed.  When using MySql, the only way I could get around this was to use `SELECT AS`, for example `SELECT id AS groupId`.

Is this still the case with MariaDB?  My duplicate column names are not limited to just the id field, so I end up with really verbose select statements.

I was hoping that MariaDB might introduce a query feature that allowed the column names to be prefaced with their table names.  For example, a query might bring back columns names `group.id` and `person.id`.

EDIT: Per the comments from Shadow, the problem is not with MariaDB (or MySql for that matter).  The result set does indeed include multiple 'id' fields.  The problem is with the client library, in my case PDO.

Comment: Note that part of the problem is that you shouldn't be using `SELECT *`, which is an antipattern.  Selecting only the columns you actually need can sometimes allow the optimizer to plan a much more efficient query, particularly when covering indexes are available.  It also reduces network traffic and resource use in the client, which typically unpacks the data whether your code references it or not.  It sounds as if you are trying to save typing at the expense of queries that are clearer to anyone else reading them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple columns in a resultset with the same name, then even mysql returns all of them, but they will have the same name in the resultset as well, unless you use a field alias. Created an sqlfiddle to prove it [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39bb4/1). Probably, your client library cannot distinguish between the 2 columns. This is a known issue for example with laravel.

Both mysql and mariadb allow you to prefix the field names with table names, but, the table name is not returned as part of the field name. However, most client libraries are able to retrieve metadata for the columns in a resultset returned by mysql / mariadb, which would include the table name for non-calculated columns. See for example [mysqli_fetch_field_direct()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php) function.

You can use the table name retrieved from metadata to determine which id column belongs to which table.

Comment: One exception:  the `JOIN` key is not duplicated when you use the syntax `FROM a JOIN b USING(blah)`.

Comment: It is not an exception. If there is no 2 columns with the same name, then the whole question does not apply. 2 columns may have the same name in 2 tables even if they are not used in the join condition.